# Two columns' results are coming in the same column in R

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I have a data frame with "Sol.grp" (non-numeric) and "age" (numeric) columns. I'm trying to store mean of age and count of observations in two separate columns.

**I used the following code:**

```
> summary <- data.frame(aggregate(age~sol.grp, data=na.omit(all.tkts), FUN=function(x) c(mean= mean(x), count=length(x))))
```

**Mean & Count** are coming in the same column (shown below)
I do not know what's wrong. Any ideas? Thanks in advance for your help !

**Edit:** The example dataset is shown at the end

```
row sol.grp           Mean
1   Account  A      187.7154
2   Account  B      215.7747
3   WMID            199.0201
4   Qty             254.5545
5   PM              210.7109
6   CS              165.6500
7   ED              158.5483
8   TM              271.1966
9                   39.0000
10                  131.0000
11                  189.0000
12                  149.0000
13                  3533.0000
14                  2.0000
15                  338.0000
16                  58.0000
```

**Example data:** (Top 20 rows)

```
sol.grp     age
Account A   29.6
Account B   29.6
WMID        26.9
Qty         1.7
PM          3.0
CS          2043.8
ED          24.3
TM          24.3
Account A   24.3
Account B   133.3
WMID        27.0
Qty         2.1
PM          29.2
CS          29.4
ED          97.8
TM          192.9
Account A   651.6
Account B   148.6
WMID        125.2
Qty         31.1
```

Comment: Better would be to show an example dataset using `dput` ie. `dput(head(data, 20))` Perhaps `do.call(data.frame, aggregate(...))` Not tested without an example data.

Comment: @Mathan Couldn't reproduce the problem using an example data `set.seed(25);
all.tkts <- data.frame(sol.grp=sample(c("Account A", "Account B", "WMID", "Qty", "PM", "CS", "ED", "TM"), 50, replace=TRUE), age=sample(25:55, 50, replace=TRUE))`  But of course you need `do.call(data.frame, ...)` to coerce the matrix output into dataframe.

Comment: I have added example data set at the end now. Thanks !

Comment: @Mathan I tested it using your example (updated version) and couldn't find any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 res1 <- setDT(all.tkts)[, list(Mean=mean(age, na.rm=TRUE), Count=.N),
                                            keyby=sol.grp]
```

The `aggregate` results did not show any anomaly using the below example

```
 res2 <- do.call(data.frame,aggregate(age~sol.grp, 
          data=na.omit(all.tkts), FUN=function(x) c(mean= mean(x), count=length(x))))

 res2 
 #    sol.grp   age.mean age.count
 #1 Account A  235.16667         3
 #2 Account B  103.83333         3
 #3        CS 1036.60000         2
 #4        ED   61.05000         2
 #5        PM   16.10000         2
 #6       Qty   11.63333         3
 #7        TM  108.60000         2
 #8      WMID   59.70000         3
```

#### data

```
 all.tkts <- structure(list(sol.grp = structure(c(1L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 
 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 6L), .Label = c("Account A", 
 "Account B", "CS", "ED", "PM", "Qty", "TM", "WMID"), class = "factor"), 
age = c(29.6, 29.6, 26.9, 1.7, 3, 2043.8, 24.3, 24.3, 24.3, 
133.3, 27, 2.1, 29.2, 29.4, 97.8, 192.9, 651.6, 148.6, 125.2, 
31.1)), .Names = c("sol.grp", "age"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: @Mathan No problem.  I am curious to know how you got the output you mentioned in the post.

Comment: :-) Did you try my code at your end and got the same results?

Comment: @Mathan Yes I did, only difference is that it won't change the `coerce the matrix to dataframe. ie. 2nd column.

Answer (score 0):

Following from your own code works well:

```
aggregate(age~sol.grp, data=na.omit(all.tkts), FUN=function(x) c(mean= mean(x), count=length(x)))
    sol.grp   age.mean  age.count
1 Account A  235.16667    3.00000
2 Account B  103.83333    3.00000
3        CS 1036.60000    2.00000
4        ED   61.05000    2.00000
5        PM   16.10000    2.00000
6       Qty   11.63333    3.00000
7        TM  108.60000    2.00000
8      WMID   59.70000    3.00000
```

Just avoid putting data.frame around aggregate, since aggregate returns a data.frame.

EDIT:

The details of output are:

```
> dd = aggregate(age~sol.grp, data=na.omit(all.tkts), FUN=function(x) c(mean= mean(x), count=length(x)))
> str(dd)
'data.frame':   8 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ sol.grp: Factor w/ 8 levels "Account A","Account B",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
 $ age    : num [1:8, 1:2] 235.2 103.8 1036.6 61 16.1 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr  "mean" "count"
> 
> dd$sol.grp
[1] Account A Account B CS        ED        PM        Qty       TM        WMID     
Levels: Account A Account B CS ED PM Qty TM WMID

> dd$age
           mean count
[1,]  235.16667     3
[2,]  103.83333     3
[3,] 1036.60000     2
[4,]   61.05000     2
[5,]   16.10000     2
[6,]   11.63333     3
[7,]  108.60000     2
[8,]   59.70000     3
> 
> dd$age[,2]
[1] 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3
> 
> dd$age[,1]
[1]  235.16667  103.83333 1036.60000   61.05000   16.10000   11.63333  108.60000   59.70000
```